continuity of a bijection between open and closed
Context: I'm trying to prove that a point on the boundary of a manifold has coordinates $(x_1,..., x_{n-1},0)$.
My question.
Let $R^n_+=\{(x_1,...,x_{n-1},0)\}$.
Let $a=(a_1,..., a_{n-1},0)$.
Let $A$ be open in $R^n$ and $B$ be an open part of $R^n_+$ (induced topology) containing $a$.
Let $f:A\to B$ be a bijection.
Then I want to prove that $f$ cannot be continuous. More precisely, I want to prove that $f$ has a discontinuity point which is not $f^{-1}(a)$.
I am able to prove that a bijection $f:(0,1)\to (0,1]$ cannot be continuous because it cannot satisfy the intermediate value theorem around $f^{-1}(1)$.

This is invariance of domain. Highly nontrivial theorem. It implies that no subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$ if $n<m$. As for discontinuity point, it can be anything, including all points in the domain.

Adding a differentiability hypothesis (which is okay for my "manifold" purpose), it becomes easier. See this video,.
